# ERROR android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib Could not launch 'C:\Users: No such file or directory

Tags: android, react-native, path, android-emulator

I am trying to work with the native native for a school project, but when executing the following command in cmd: `emulator -version` he returned this error to me:

```
[4640]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
```

Could not launch 'C:\Users\gusta..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe': No such file or directory

already changed the path in several ways and I think the problem is not this so if someone can help me grateful

Answer (score 8):

There are two emulator executables in the sdk (as of now):

- `sdk/tools/emulator`
- `sdk/emulator/emulator`

The `emulator` executable has to be added in the PATH variable, in a way so that

`sdk/emulator/emulator` comes before `sdk/tools/emulator`

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer of IronBlossom.

On mac these are the important environment variables that need to be adjusted.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Make sure that `emulator` comes before `tools`

Comment: OMG. How nit-picky can you get. Google, please!

Answer (score 4):

Do this to solve the error:

- Edit the system environment variables
- Make sure you have set user variable for ANDROID_HOME
- Remove any variable /path/to/android-sdk/tools from user and system environment variable.
- Save and exit

Comment: To remove path to .../android/sdk/tools did the trick for me. 
I've ended up with:

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<dirk>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this error:

Your system variables should look like below:

```
“C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk”    -ANDROID_HOME
“C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin” -PATH
“C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools”  -PATH
“C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator” - PATH
“C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools" -PATH
```

This worked for me.